# Appending slice not working as expected

Tags: google-app-engine, go

New to golang. Im trying to store all the waypoints sent over from our app side, but with a batch size of 100, here's my code

```
json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(payload)

// seperate waypoints into groups
limit := 100
seperated := [][]*waypoint.Waypoint{}

// payload is from api call, basically plain json data
for i, wp := range payload.Batch {
    if i%limit == 0 {
        seperated = append(seperated, []*waypoint.Waypoint{})
    }
    last := seperated[len(seperated)-1]
    last = append(last, wp)
}
```

Not sure what went long but seems i cant what i expected..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a copy of your slice when you assign it to `last`, so when you append that isn't reflected in the outer `seperated` slice.

Assign it directly like so:

```
last := len(seperated)-1
seperated[last] = append(seperated[last], wp)
```